# How to invite friends using facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fbml

**Note: dont think it as repeat of any other similar questions.**

We have options to display the 'Invite Friends' dialog using Legacy FBML and javascript (it also uses FBML) and they are working fine.

As facebook states that these FBML are going to be deprecated, is there any other better to way to Invite/ send requests to friends to join an application ..

I'm in the initial phase of my db app development and dont want to use the `to be deprecated` stuffs.. Is there any option using GRAPH Api?

**Edit:** I'm using PHP SDK for this app development and is there any function we could use from that?

Comment: As long as i know there is no method in the graph api by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) is currently the only non-deprecated method of inviting your friends to a Facebook application.  I doubt there will be a graph api method to create them as it would seem to be too easy to abuse, but getting, clearing and deleting them are available with the graph api.